# Find path on a matrix to get max value

Tags: java, algorithm, computer-science

I know, this is an old problem, if given a matrix like：

```
[1 1 2 3，
 2 3 4 4，
 3 4 1 3，
 2 1 3 4]
```

Start at a given position, from right to left, only move right or up or down, can not go back in same way and stop at right, find a path to get max value.

I am considering to use DP(May need try all possible path and calculate value), but it seems it will cost a lot of memory since it store all the possible solutions and may also be slow.

I am wondering if there are any other thoughts or ways to make a better solution? A quicker solution if possible?

Comment: Write how do you consider using DP? Give more details about your solution. As it stands right now, it looks like you heard that you can use dp here and just added a sentence about DP just to look nice.

Comment: Well, greedy algorithm can not be used since maybe one place have a too large value, so DP since be the only way.

Comment: this tells nothing about "how do you consider using DP".

Comment: If you have somewhere to start, and somewhere to end (check point). I think BFS work too.

Comment: Where do you start? Based on your description you can start anywhere on the right side and finish anywhere on the left. Is this right?

Comment: Maybe this question is more for the [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) part of StackExchange. Why the "java" keyword?

Comment: @SalvadorDali Em, yes. Suppose it can start at a given place not necessary to start in a fixed place.

Comment: @maxime.bochon Alright...I fix it. Because I use JAVA.

Comment: @OmgIkilledKennny sorry but what would be the output of this program?

Comment: `only move left or right`, can you really move to the right? I'd expect to only allow moving left...

Comment: @radoh Sorry man, fixed.

Comment: @fuzzy28 Anything, its just a general question, it can output path or final value. Lets say final value.

Comment: @OmgIkilledKennny `From right to left, only move right`, man now it doesn't make any sense at all :D

Comment: @radoh How about this now?

Comment: do you have negative numbers?

Comment: @OmgIkilledKennny Well, you've written `From right to left, only move right or up or down,` so you're effectively stuck on the rightmost column...

Comment: @SalvadorDali Em..I don't know how this will affect the algorithm? If so I think can treat as a block.

Comment: @OmgIkilledKennny as you asked the question now, start in the rightmost column, top row; then move all the way down to the bottom row. There's your maximal path :)

Comment: @CompuChip I said its a given place man...

Comment: Sorry @OmgIkilledKennny didn't go through all the comments, maybe you could edit relevant information into the question. Anyway, if you are sure the question as it stands is correct, I'd be happy to post an answer. It seems quite trivial though.

Comment: @CompuChip Edited, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there is a way to do a DP and I just can't quickly find it. Because no one answered it so far I will give a graph method. Create a directed graph where an edge from A to B will be equal to the number in that vertex. It is clear from your description that it will not have any cycles. You will get a grid graph like this, but only directed:

[image]

Now get an vertex source which is somewhere on the right and connect it to the first layer (put all the edges equal to 0). The same with a destination, but it is on the left.

Now run [longest path in directed acyclic graph](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-longest-path-directed-acyclic-graph/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to optimize for memory, you might try Backtracking. This would involve only storing the current path, and the path and value for the best solution yet.

Outline is:

1. You store a list of steps (right, up, down)
2. You go depth-first so to speak, try to make a new step if you can
3. If you can't, just go back one and change the step to the next possible direction. (Store this path if it's better than previously stored one).
4. If there is no next possible direction for the step, repeat 3.
5. If all possibilities are exhausted, return the stored best path.

Backtracking at wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking